# If elseif condition inside foreach with array

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement, foreach

I'm using a `if elseif` condition inside the foreach loop. Inside both `if` and `elseif` two different functions are calling and retrieving value to same array `$nice[]`. If I run the following code, only the `if` condition is working.

```
$youtube = array(
             'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCwRJUg3tcQ1&list=PLv5BUbwWA5RYaM6E-QiE8WxoKwyBnozV2&index=4',
             'http://vimeo.com/channels/vimeogirls/87973054123',
             'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCwRJUg3tcQ2&feature=relate',
             'http://youtube.com/v/nCwRJUg3tcQ3?feature=youtube_gdata_player');  

$nice = array();  

foreach ($youtube as $url) {
    if(preg_grep("/youtu/i", $youtube)){
        $nice[] = getYoutubeId($url);
    }elseif(preg_grep("/vimeo/i", $youtube)){
        $nice[] = getVimeoId($url);
    }
}  

print_r($nice);  

function getVimeoId($url)
{
    if (preg_match('#(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:player.)?vimeo.com/(?:[a-z]*/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*#', $url, $m)) {
        return 'v_'.$m[1];
    }
    return false;
}  

function getYoutubeId($url)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (isset($parts['host'])) {
        $host = $parts['host'];
        if (false === strpos($host, 'youtube') &&
            false === strpos($host, 'youtu.be')
            ) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (isset($parts['query'])) {
        parse_str($parts['query'], $qs);
        if (isset($qs['v'])) {
            return 'y_'.$qs['v'];
        }
        else if (isset($qs['vi'])) {
            return 'y_'.$qs['vi'];
        }
    }
    if (isset($parts['path'])) {
        $path = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));
        return 'y_'.$path[count($path) - 1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

The current output is:

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => y_nCwRJUg3tcQ1 
        [1] => 
        [2] => y_nCwRJUg3tcQ2 
        [3] => y_nCwRJUg3tcQ3 
    )
```

There is no value in `[1]` position.

Comment: first guess would be that getVimeoId returns null, false or similar. please check that method for errors and/or provide its code, so we can have a look.

Comment: It might be useful of we see what the two functions do. As it is those functions that are doing whatever is being done correctly or wronly. **Dont you think**

Comment: @FranzGleichmann updated the code.

Comment: A bit of code indentation would make your code easier for us to read but **more importantly easier for you to debug**

Comment: If I'm not missing something, those `preg_grep()` checks make no sense at all. What you probably want is to check for `youtu` and `vimeo` in `$url` and not in `$youtube`. And `stripos()` would be the better choice here IMO. I don't see a reason for a regular expression.

Comment: @simon yeah there is no problem with regular expression. can you please explain what you said.

Comment: Replace `if(preg_grep("/youtu/i", $youtube))` with something like `if (stripos($url, "youtu") !== false)` or see the answer you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First-off, your `if()` Clause is checking on the main array`$youtube` instead of the value: `$url`.
> Perhaps, the snippet below helps:

```
    $youtube = array(
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCwRJUg3tcQ1&list=PLv5BUbwWA5RYaM6E-QiE8WxoKwyBnozV2&index=4',
        'http://vimeo.com/channels/vimeogirls/87973054123',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCwRJUg3tcQ2&feature=relate',
        'http://youtube.com/v/nCwRJUg3tcQ3?feature=youtube_gdata_player');

    $nice = array();

    foreach ($youtube as $url) {
        if(preg_match("#youtu#i", $url)){
            $nice[] = getYoutubeId($url);
        }elseif(preg_match("#vimeo#i", $url)){
            $nice[] = getVimeoId($url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: work perfectly maahn... Thank you so much. You save my day :)